# Facebook deeplink doesn't work in web browser

Tags: facebook, deep-linking

We're trying to implement deep links in facebook ads. Everything works fine when we open ad link in facebook app: if our app is curretly installed then facebook app launches our app and passes the deep link into it. Also if our app is not installed and we open ad link in facebook app then it redirects to AppStore and we recieve deferred deep link from facebook inside our app.
But when we try to reproduce all these scenarios using facebook browser version, none of the cases are working (neither deep link nor deferred deep link)
Is it possible at all to make deep links work in web environment?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've asked Facebook support and received the answer:

> Deep link is designed to work in apps only. It doesn't work with a
>   browser. Please don't worry because it's working as expected!

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/535030953629446/?disable_redirect=0